# Block access to http version, not https version?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, https

I have been looking everywhere for how to create a rewrite rule that only applies to http:// versions of a website and not the https:// version.

Basically, for a login page I am trying to block all access to the http version so that the user is forced to login through the secure page.

In my situation, the example is:

```
http://shop.example.com/admin (Blocked)

https://shop.example.com/admin (Access)
```

Can anyone help me out with this? And if I am searching the wrong keywords, please do not lower my score. Simply offer me the advice for what to look for and I will remove the question and continue with my searches.

Thanks

EDIT:
Another issue is this website is an eCommerce CMS. Therefore, there is only one index.php file and one .htaccess file for the entire website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shop\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^admin - [F,NC]
```

This will return forbidden error for all the `http://shop.example.com/admin` requests.

Comment: Hi! Perfect.. I am very sorry but I forgot some important information! I have added this to the original question.

Comment: That is fine, this rule will still work fine. Just make sure this rule is **very first rule** in your main .htaccess

Comment: I have tried your solution, unfortunately this solution doesn't work for my scenario. I have added your solution and obviously changed the example.com to my domain. The only other rewrites in this htaccess file are simple 301 redirects.

Comment: This rule definitely works as there is not much happening here. As I have already said this one must be **very first rule**. If you have only one domain then delete 2nd `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}` line also.

Comment: This unfortunately broke the use of my site for some reason. I have tried the following in my admin directory which seems to be working fine. `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}`

Comment: Inside admin directory you can just do: `RewriteRule ^ - [F]` to block.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me something new today! :) I appreciate your help.